# Join float list into space-separated string in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of floats in python:

```
a = [1.2, 2.9, 7.4]
```

I want to join them to produce a space-separated string - ie.:

```
1.2 2.9 7.4
```

However, when I try:

```
print " ".join(a)
```

I get an error because they're floats, and when I try:

```
print " ".join(str(a))
```

I get

```
[ 1 . 2 ,   1 . 8 ,   5 . 2 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 ]
```

How can I join all of the elements, while converting the elements (individually) to strings, without having to loop through them all?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to convert each entry of the list to a string, not the whole list at once:

```
print " ".join(map(str, a))
```

If you want more control over the conversion to string (e.g. control how many digits to print), you can use

```
print "".join(format(x, "10.3f") for x in a)
```

See [the documentation of the syntax of format specifiers](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: +1 Alternatively to the first one, `" ".join(str(x) for x in a)` (in Python 2.x, this also have a small practical advantage - it won't allocate memory for all the intermediate strings at once).

Comment: For formatted strings, `' '.join("%10.3f" % x for x in a)` is twice as fast as the `format(x, "10.3f")` version on my machine (tested with a list of 1000 `random()` floats).

Answer (score 6):

Actually you have to loop through them. With a generator or list comprehension that looks pretty clean:

```
print " ".join(str(i) for i in a)
```

(map loops through them, as does the format code)

The generator has the advantage over the list comprehension of not generating a second intermediate list, thus preserving memory. List comprehension would be:

```
print " ".join([str(i) for i in a])
```