# Lists and indexes gives error because list out of range

Tags: python, listview, indexing

I get an error when I try to run my funtion.
I know the reason. but I search a way to fix this.

```
list2=['name','position','salary','bonus']
list3=['name','position','salary']


def funtionNew(list):
    print(len(list))
    po= '{} {} {} {}'.format(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3])
    print(po)


funtionNew(list3)
```

So that I can make this for list2

```
po='{}{}{}{}'..format(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3])
```

and make this for list3

```
po='{}{}{}'..format(list[0],list[1],list[2])
```

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your list into a space-separated string? If so, it may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6507431/4636715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def funtionNew(list):
    print(len(list))

    string_for_formatting = '{} ' * len(list)
    po = string_for_formatting.format(*list)

    print(po)
```

This creates a string with a variable number of {} terms according to the length of your list, and then uses format on the list. The asterisk *, unpacks the elements of your list as inputs for the function.

Answer (score 3):

From the function implementation it seems like you try to concat the list items with spaces in between so you can try instead -

```
po=' '.join(list)
```

This is independent from the list length, however you have to make sure that all the items in the list are strings. So you can do the following -

```
po = ' '.join[str(s) for s in list]
```